# How to access database and create table in Rhomobile framework

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to Rhomobile. I am developing application in Rhomobile. Can any one guide me How can view the database and tables in RHOMOBILE and How can create a database and tables.

I have seen the RHOMOBILE tutorials. I did't get any clear idea. Pleas Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If in Windows you can view your database in the file under your gem's folder in the path
`platform/wm/bin/win32/rhodes/Debug/rho/db/syncdblocal.sqlite`

You can use `SQLite Database Browser` (http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net) to manipulate your data. Download it at [SourceForge SQLiteBrowser Project Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/latest/download).