# How to create database (SQLite file) in RhoMobile Suite

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to Rhomobile.
I am developing a mobile app (ruby code). I want to create a database, add some elements and finally show those elements on the view page. How to go with this?

Also what is the location of .sqlite file where our database is stored and is its name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213152/how-to-access-database-and-create-table-in-rhomobile-framework  http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.4/guide/rhom_ruby

Comment: @Casper the sqlite where data is saved is not coming same every time. At   one time it was syncdblocal.sqlite. After creating table through fixed schema method it is being saved in syncdbuser.sqlite

Comment: Sorry Vivek, I'm not familiar with RhoMobile. I tried to find what I could through the docs, but it wasn't much :(